# How much does it cost for a eviction lawsuit in Mumbai?

Tags: india, real-estate, fees, legal

I have a tenant who is refusing to leave. He has not paid any rent. How much will it cost to evict this tenant?
How much can i expect an attorney to charge me for court proceedings and how much will the court proceeding cost me in Mumbai?
The price of the property is around Rs.60,00,000 or Rs.60 Lakh. Deposit from the tenant is around Rs.60,000/- and monthly rent is around Rs.9000/-.
Approximate Rupees amount should do

Comment: I don't think this type of question in on topic for this site. You should consult an attorney in India if you want an idea of the cost.

Comment: Besides, the question is often how much it will cost _not_ to evict.

Comment: I think that *general* cost requests, as the question is mostly phrased, is fine - this is something an individual landlord might want to know, in order to tell if his/her attorney is asking a reasonable fee, for example.

Comment: I have an attorney who is quoting something to the order of 10% of the price of the property. I just find that quote ridiculous. So a property worth Rs. 60,00,000/- or 60 Lakh will cost Rs.6,00,000/- or 6 Lakh.

Comment: Get other quotes, obviously.. But below a certain amount it isn't worth the attorney's time and don't know enough about your economy to know if that might be an issue.

Answer (score 2):

Any such lawsuit would cost few lakhs. It depends on the lawyer you hire and depends on how much the tenant is will be pay his lawyer. The lawyer fees vary from Rs 500 per hour to Rs 50,000 or even higher. Plus there would be other fees like attending a hearing, etc. So very soon the bill would go way up. Plus the decision in Magistrate court can be appealed in sessions court can further go high court etc. All this would be a time and money consuming. Since this is treated as civilian dispute, the average time to settle the case is around 10 years. If you tenant has deep pockets the case can easily drag on for more years.

If you have a lawyer working with no upfront fees and taking his fixed 10% only when the tenant is evicted, go for it. Ensure that the contract is with lawyer is clear that payment would be;

- its not just the court ruling, but actual eviction that matters
- what would happen if the lawyer say for 2-3 years is not able to win the decision / or after winning not able to enforce the court order.

An alternate option would be to see if you can make an informal offer to the Tenant of few lakhs for him to leave peacefully without getting into legal.

Comment: Infact that is exactly what i did . I paid the guy about 1 lakh and essentially avoided the situation. Thank you for your comment..